# How do I display all of my leaderboard entries in one canvas

Tags: c#, json, user-interface, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

I'm having trouble with my leaderboards. I want to show all of my entries/ID's in the game (on the canvas)apart from each other so underneath eachother. and for every entry a new text so it would be a proper leaderboards that I can also filter. the code that I used is here with underneath the output. I used mySQL and PHP to link the data and it goes through the JSon helper to wrap the data.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;



public class Leaderboard : MonoBehaviour
{

// Array of all the employees

[System.Serializable]
public class LeaderBoard
{
    public string ID;
    public string Team;
    public string VerkoopA;
    public string VerkoopB;
    public string NPS;
    public string Conversie;
}

Text txt;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Getting the leaderboard data from mySQL.
    WWW leaderboardsData = new WWW("http://localhost/leaderboards.php");
    yield return leaderboardsData;

    string leaderboardsDataString = fixJson(leaderboardsData.text);

    LeaderBoard[] leaderboard;
    // letting the data wrap through json in order to be used.
    leaderboard = JsonHelper.FromJson<LeaderBoard>(leaderboardsDataString);

    foreach (LeaderBoard employee in leaderboard)
    {
        Debug.Log(employee);

        DisplayLeaderboards(employee);
    }

}

string fixJson(string value)
{
    value = "{\"Items\":" + value + "}";
    return value;
}


// Display the leaderboards 1 by 1.
void DisplayLeaderboards(LeaderBoard employeeApart)
{   
    txt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = employeeApart.ID + "     " + employeeApart.Team + "     " + employeeApart.VerkoopA + "     "  + employeeApart.VerkoopB + "     " + employeeApart.NPS + "     " + employeeApart.Conversie;

    Debug.Log(employeeApart.ID + "   " + employeeApart.Team + "   " + employeeApart.VerkoopA + "   " + employeeApart.VerkoopB + "   " +employeeApart.NPS + "   " + employeeApart.Conversie);
    Debug.Log("ID: " + employeeApart.ID);
    Debug.Log("Team: " + employeeApart.Team);
    Debug.Log("VerkoopA: " + employeeApart.VerkoopA);
    Debug.Log("VerkoopB: " + employeeApart.VerkoopB);
    Debug.Log("NPS: " + employeeApart.NPS);
    Debug.Log("Conversie: " + employeeApart.Conversie);
}

}
```

Output:

> Leaderboard+LeaderBoard
>   3   2   12   12   40   10
>   ID: 3
>   Team: 2
>   VerkoopA: 12
>   VerkoopB: 12
>   NPS: 40
>   Conversie: 10
>   Leaderboard+LeaderBoard
>   1   2   35   12   25   18
>   ID: 1
>   Team: 2
>   VerkoopA: 35
>   VerkoopB: 12
>   NPS: 25
>   Conversie: 18
>   Leaderboard+LeaderBoard
>   2   1   55   2   12   40
>   ID: 2
>   Team: 1
>   VerkoopA: 55
>   VerkoopB: 2
>   NPS: 12
>   Conversie: 40

Now the numbers are all correct and it does it for every item in the array however I put the script on my leaderboard text game object but it only shows one of the entries. I need to have every entry in the leaderboard but I can't get it to work. So it needs to add a new text for every entry and show this entry on the text in Unity so my leaderboard can work.